# is data caching possible in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

is data caching possible in silverlight?
if yes can anyone suggest me to find good articles for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of articles on the subject:

- [IsolatedStorage as a Silverlight object cache](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/09/24/silverlight-isolated-storage-caching.aspx)
- [In memory cache for Silverlight 2 and 3](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/03/29/in-memory-cache-for-silverlight-2-and-3/)

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Library [Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight&referringTitle=Home) from [patterns & practices](http://msdn.com/practices) includes a Caching application block, which supports both in-memory and isolated storage caching and flexible configuration of the expiration policies (programmatically or via external config). Take a look.

Note, it's a code preview now, but should be releasing as a final in May.

Comment: In addition, take a look at this screencast that demoes the Caching application block for Silverlight. http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Enterprise-Library-for-Silverlight-Data-Caching-demo